# Unable to get the result from Google machine learning Cloud REST API

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to run a job using Google Cloud Machine Learning REST-API  [**ml.jobs.project.create**](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/m/v1/ml.projects.jobs.create)

The latest job that I submitted has job id '**drivermonitoring20180109335**'. Here on completion of the job, message '**job completed successfully**' is displayed but I cannot see any desired output file in the specified location. Output logs can be seen in fig1[image: logs on running the job]

Also I would like to keep in-front of you my few observations while running this job id:

**i)** Running the job took very less time in comparison to any other job that I executed before.

**ii)** While running jobs before, every job earlier was executed via two different tasks viz a)**master-replica-0** and b)**service** (refer fig2)[image] but this *job didn't have master-replica-0* task(refer fig3)[image] I tried to Google the issue, but was unable to find any solution related to the issue.

So I can infer that the task that I was trying to run is being scheduled but the python script that I am trying to run is never scheduled to be executed.

Kindly let me know if you require more screenshots or if you want to have a look at the project structure to help with the issue.

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT 1: Added JSON while making API call***

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/drivermonitoringsystem/jobs?key={YOUR_API_KEY}



{
 "trainingInput": {
  "pythonModule": "trainer.retrain",
  "args": [
   "--bottleneck_dir=ModelTraining/tf_files/bottlenecks \
    --model_dir=ModelTraining/tf_files/models/ \
    --architecture=mobilenet_0.50_224 \
    --output_graph=gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
    --output_labels=gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
    --image_dir=gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/dataset224x224/"
  ],
  "region": "us-central1",
  "packageUris": [
   "gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/ModelTraining4.tar.gz"
  ],
  "jobDir": "gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/tf_files/",
  "runtimeVersion": "1.4"
 },
 "jobId": "job_id201801101535"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just run myself some sample jobs using both the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/) and the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/), and everything has just worked fine in both of the cases. It looks like, in your case, the job was never executed, as there is no cluster created for processing the job itself (that is why *master-replica-0* is missing).

The jobs that you had run previously and which had worked were launched also using the REST API, or instead with `gcloud` or a Client Library?

Here I share an example JSON I used when making the API call to [ml.projects.jobs.create](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/create) through the API Explorer link you shared, I suggest you try adapting it to your requirements and check if you got any missing field:

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<YOUR_PROJECT>/jobs?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "jobId": "<JOB_ID>",
 "trainingInput": {
  "jobDir": "gs://<LOCATION_TO_STORE_OUTPUTS>",
  "runtimeVersion": "1.4",
  "region": "<REGION>",
  "packageUris": [
   "gs://<PATH_TO_YOUR_TRAINER>/trainer-0.0.0.tar.gz"
  ],
  "pythonModule": "<PYTHON_MODULE_TO_RUN>",
  "args": [
   "--train-files",
   "gs://<PATH_TO_YOUR_TRAINING_DATA>/data.csv",
   "--eval-files",
   "gs://<PATH_TO_YOUR_TEST_DATA>/test.csv",
   "--train-steps",
   "100",
   "--eval-steps",
   "10",
   "--verbosity",
   "DEBUG"
  ]
 }
}
```

Change [TrainingInput](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#traininginput) to [PredictionInput](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#predictioninput) (and the appropriate child fields) if you are trying to run a prediction job instead of a training one, as in this example.

Comment: The jobs that I had run previously and which had worked were launched using the REST API.

Comment: And they had exactly the same configuration as the one that failed?

Comment: Yes. It had the same configuration. However I didn't use the field _runtimeVersion_ in my API call. Hope it didn't made the difference. I have added the JSON file as EDIT 1 to the Question

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. I guess *runtimeVersion* should not be the problem here, as it is an optional field which, if missing, will choose the latest stable version. I understand that, for some reason, that precise job failed to deploy properly. Maybe you can try re-submitting it. Can you confirm that you have run the exact same API call (just changing the jobID) and it has worked other times?

Comment: Actually I have never been able to successfully implement this script using the API. However earlier, my python script _trainer.retrain_ used to execute partially before I get some error logs. Also to add, I have successfully ran the script and have got the desired output using Google Cloud Shell.

Comment: So if I got it right, you have run the exact same trainer (i.e. *trainer.retrain* in *ModelTraining4.tar.gz*) using `gcloud` and it worked (or only was partially executed)? That sounds strange and might be worth looking at. In any case, please try something: go to one of the old jobs which you were able to run successfully (I guess those using gcloud); there consult its master-replica-0 logs; the first one should include something like "Running task with arguments..." and there you can find a JSON-like description of how the job was run. Try to reproduce the same content in your API call.

Comment: Using gcloud I was able to successfully implement the script. However I will surely implement the thing you just suggested and will let you know the result. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: My _ModelTraining4.tar.gz_ contains a folder _ModelTraining_ and _ModelTraining_ consist of the folder _trainer_ which has _retrain.py_ file.

Comment: Recently I made some changes and somehow master-replica-0 is executing but I am getting following error logs: Command '['python', '-m', u'trainer.retrain', u'--bottleneck_dir=<BUCKET>/ModelTraining/tf_files/bottlenecks --model_dir=<BUCKET>/ModelTraining/tf_files/models/ --architecture=mobilenet_0.50_224 --how_many_training_steps=500 --output_graph=<BUCKET>/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=<BUCKET>/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt --image_dir=<BUCKET>/dataset224x224/', '--job-dir', u'<BUCKET>/tf_files/']' returned non-zero exit status 255

Comment: I would suggest that you post a different question for that different topic, as maybe that way you can get more attention and it will be easier to handle than by adding comments here.